# quickly load text to excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, optimization

I'm trying to load a CSV or TSV into Excel, and for small files it works great; small files being < 5kb.  The problem is that when I attempt to load larger files into Excel the process can take a long time. The files that I need the app to load can contain anywhere from 5 - 100 columns with anywhere from 5 to 20,000 rows.

I have tried using the BackgroundWorker, Threadpools, Parallel.For, Parallel.ForEach, but they all seem to have the same performance for this task.

The app itself is designed to take a list of headers from a separate text file, then load it into Excel, apply formatting, then loads the actual CSV/TSV file into Excel.

Here's what I have so far, this sub gets kicked off by the background worker:

```
Private Sub LoadTextFile(ByVal xlApp As Excel.Application, ByVal xlWb As Excel.Workbook, ByVal xlWs As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal xlRange As Excel.Range)
    Dim SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    If xlWs Is Nothing Then
        xlWs = DirectCast(xlWb.Sheets.Add(After:=xlWb.Sheets(xlWb.Sheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet), Excel.Worksheet)
    End If

    'Read lines and store in a string array
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(FileToLoad)

    'Parse and write lines to Excel
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        'Set new row range
        xlRange = xlWs.Range(startCol + (i + 2).ToString + ":" + endCol + (i + 2).ToString)

        'Parse the line to load
        Dim lineDetail() As String =  lines(i).Split(fileDelimiter)

        'Load into Excel
        xlRange.Value = lineDetail
    Next
End Sub
```

Here are some performance times:

89 Columns -  2,000 rows: Average Load Time =  7 sec.

89 Columns -  4,000 rows: Average Load Time = 12 sec.

91 Columns - 10,000 rows: Average Load Time = 28 sec.

91 Columns - 24,000 rows: Average Load Time = 70 sec.

107Columns -  8,732 rows: Average Load Time = 17 sec.

I keep thinking, "How does Excel load these files almost instantly?!?" Anyways, I will be super grateful to anyone that can help me optimize this so getting the data into Excel doesn't take so long.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: `"How does Excel load these files almost instantly?!?" ` - Have you thought of using Excel's macro recorder to obtain the command to import a file?

Comment: @TnTinMn I have but I don't think it's flexible enough.  I would have to create 48 different macros for each of the different formats I need.  I would also need to make it as easy as possible for users to use.  The user base that I have has no idea how to use Excel macros.  Lastly, I need a way to update the columns 2x every year and I don't want to re-create 48 macros 2x every year.  The way it works now is that it pulls the headers from a text file and that can be updated super easily.

Comment: I'm not proposing that you convert your VB.Net application to a set of Excel macro's.  I'[m trying to teach you to use the macro recorder to discover Excel Object Model commands that you may not know.  It takes only a little effort to convert a VBA Interop statement to .Net Interop statement.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, and correct me if I'm wrong:  Record the macro of opening the file in Excel, then view the code of the macro in visual basic and convert that to my vb.net app?

Comment: `Record the macro of opening the file in Excel, then view the code of the macro in visual basic and convert that to my vb.net app?` Yes, but for what you are doing, opening the file is the incorrect procedure.  You want to "Get External Data" from a text file.  That will record the insertion of a QueryTable; all you want is the data, so you need to modify the code to assign the `QueryTable` to a variable so that you can call the `QueryTable.Delete` method to remove the table definition (not the data though) from the Worksheet.  Edit your question to show your code if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with and I think it works very well.  Thanks to TnTinMn for pointing me in the right direction :)

```
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range

    'Start Excel and Create Application Object
    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'Set invisible until all loading is completed
    xlApp.Visible = False

    'Get/Set references of active workbook/sheet
    xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlWb = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
    xlWs = xlWb.ActiveSheet
    xlRange = xlWs.Range("$A$1")

    'Used to specify the data type for each column.  2 = Text
    Dim array = New Object() {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 _
        , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}

    'TextFilePlatform ANSI: 1252
    With xlWs.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + cfg.filePath, Destination:=xlRange)
        .Name = "sec"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = Excel.XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = cfg.fileTSV
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = cfg.fileCSV
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = array
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh(BackgroundQuery:=False)
    End With

    'Add headers do formatting here
    '<Additional Worksheet formats here>

    xlApp.Visible = True
```